# Getting Invalid XPath Expression error while retrieving elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
        <location>DL</location>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="es">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
        <location>UP</location>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
        <location>  DL</location>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
        <location>dl </location>
    </book>
    <category>web</category>
</bookstore>
```

XPath:

Contains(/bookstore/book[@category="web"],/bookstore/category[text()="web"])

I am getting invalid expression error after running the above XPath expression.

Basically, I want to find out all those book elements whose category attribute value matches with the value contained in the category element under Books element.

Comment: Are you trying to get only `web` category books? `/bookstore/book[@category="web"]` tried this?

Comment: Not exactly.

Actually I am trying to get all those book elements whose attribute value matches with the category element(present inside bookstore root element) value.

Something like:

Return all book elements whose attribute value = value present inside the category element under bookstore root element.

Comment: The XPath expression looks OK except that "contains" should be lower-case. I doubt the XPath expression does what you want it to do (it returns a boolean true or false, not a set of book elements) but that's a different matter.

Comment: @MichaelKay: With contains function in lowercase, the expression ran but returned a false vaue. I was expecting a true value from the XPath expression. I modified my XPath expression: contains(/bookstore/book[@category="web"],string(/bookstore/category[text()="web"])) but still it is returning a false value.

Comment: The first argument of your call to contains() selects a set of nodes. If you are using XPath 1.0, then contains() converts that to a string by taking the string value of the first node in the node-set. The string value of an element does not include any attributes, so it does not contain "web", so the result is false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that should work for your.

```
/bookstore/book[@category=/bookstore/category/text()]
```

[image]

**Answer based on comment:**
if you have compare with attribute value then follow this.

```
/bookstore/book[@category=ancestor::bookstore/category/@type]
```

[image]

Comment: Or shortly: `/bookstore/book[@category=ancestor::bookstore/category]`

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response.

Just one more elementary question, if instead of the value of "category" element. I wanted to compare the value of category attribute of book element with the attribute of category element under bookstore then how can I achieve this?

Updated XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
        <location>dl </location>
    </book>
    <category type="web"/>
</bookstore>

Comment: Check the updated answer. `/bookstore/book[@category=ancestor::bookstore/category/@type]` is the answer for your comment.